# Fungi in my Solarium - how do I stop it?

Tags: mycology

Noticed fungi growing in my solarium in a few spots - probably a few spots where moisture is getting in.  It is really tough, like rubber.  Can cut some of it out with a utility knife, but even that was not an easy process.  Couldn't dig all of it out as it has gotten into some little crevices.  How can I treat this?  Tea tree oil or Oil of Oregano, or ?

The type of flooring is Bamboo.

The spotty things you see on the floor are spider droppings.. how that critter got in there is a mystery - room is always closed, way up on the 3rd floor where I never see any spiders, room is hardly used, and no openings for little flies or anything to get in for its food...?  Anyways, I digress... my real concern is to stop this fungi growth!

Thanks in advance...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Are you sure this fungi and not some sort of overzealously applied sealant? If you are sure it is fungal, does it have any odor? ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: Yes, definitely fungi.  I put the floors in myself, and this area is inside, and does not need sealant - was not there for 4 years, but this time I checked, I was surprised to see this growth.  It is a bit moist, and does smell like mushrooms...!

Comment: I'm thinking that this site is probably not the best place for this question — maybe [diy.se] would be a better fit? ——— That being said, fungi are tough, so I doubt any surface treatment is going be much help. Since fungi generally like moisture I'd check for leaks from outside and inside — also make sure the humidity in the room is being kept reasonably low. After that I think you would want to remove what growth you can (replace the affected floor boards if possible).